# I need stable module system in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, module, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel, I want to build application in modular structure. Please can you refer me the stable package, which provide stable modular structure.

I have tried following packages for this purpose but each of them have issues.

Pingpong
nWidart/Laravel Module
caffeinated/modules

So i need to select perfect one. Please help.

I need your help for some general questions?

Q1. Another question in my mind that how can we set the centralized assets for all modules. I need to know centralized asset management for all modules / whole application?

Q2. In my application a lot picture will be uploaded on each project. around 25 pictures and document will be uploaded. Where i should place them. In Assets or storage or i should use third party site for images like we upload video on youtube etc. Last one how to upload 15 images at once quickly?

Q3. Why we use the .html in urls, do we really need this laravel? How to accomplish this technique?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For Moduler Approach see below link :

[Main Resource](https://ziyahanalbeniz.blogspot.com.tr/2015/03/modular-structure-in-laravel-5.html)

[Laravel Package](https://github.com/Artem-Schander/L5Modular)

[My Article](http://nahid.im/diary/read/23)

Answer of Q1 **:** Use **public** folder in laravel

Answer of Q2 **:** Use **public** folder or **storage/app/public** folder for store you image or video. If you choose **storage/app/public** then create a symbolic link in public folder. [Read Taylor Otwell Article](http://taylorotwell.com/spark-storage/)

Answer of Q3 **:** Question Not Clear

Comment: Thanks, for your kind response. 3rd question is about url, I have seen sites they use .html in url instead of .php. Why we use it. How to enable cashing in Laravel

Answer (score 0):

if you are not comfortable with mentioned packages you should try to implement your structure based on domain driven design, also take a look at this thread :
[folder structure in laravel](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/folder-and-namespace-structure-with-ddd)

A1 : you should put them in the public directory.
A2 : put uploaded images in storage directory or you can use third party sites as well.
A3 : i can't understand your last question !
laravel does not show .html in urls by default.

Comment: Thanks, for your kind response. 3rd question is about url, I have seen sites they use .html in url instead of .php. Why we use it. How to enable cashing in Laravel?

Comment: @ghulamjafar you can enable .html or .php or whatever you like by modifying .htaccess file also for caching pls read the docs : [Cache](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/cache)

Answer (score 0):

I have created a package for the one like you who wants to implement modular way in Laravel. All you have to do is use that package and you'll have separate workspace for each module.

```
composer require yubarajshrestha/ym
```

Add the service provider to config/app.php

```
YubarajShrestha\YM\YMServiceProvider::class,
```

```
YubarajShrestha\YM\YMModuleProvider::class,
```

Add following line after `"App\": "app/"` in composer.json

**"YModules\": "YModules/"**

Example:

`"psr-4": {
    "App\\": "app/",
    "YModules\\": "YModules/"
}`

`php artisan vendor:publish`

`php artisan migrate`

`composer dump-autoload -o`

You're now good to go on...

For More visit:

[Laravel Module](https://github.com/yubarajshrestha/laravel-module)